# Append draggable to dynamically created seating chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I created a function to generate seats around a table on the fly that are evenly spaced. The problem is that I want to drag names from a list and have them append to the seats as children. However, I'm not able to drag, drop and append to these dynamically created seat divs. Suggestions?

JSBin for better readability: http://jsbin.com/papoqih/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
function renderSeats(num){
  
  var diff = 1 / num;
  var seats = '';
  
  for( i=0; i<num; i++){
    var rotate = (diff * 360) * i;
   seats += '<div class="seat-wrap"\
                  style="transform:rotate('+rotate+'deg);">\
                <div class="seat"></div>\
              </div>'
  }

  document.querySelector('.seats').innerHTML = seats;

}
$("select[name=tableCap]").change(function() {
  renderSeats($(this).val());
});

$(".nameContainer").draggable();
$(".seat").droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui)
  {
    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this))
  }
});

$(function(){
  renderSeats($("select[name=tableCap]").val());
});
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
#seatingChartContainer
{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#seatingChartListContainer
{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.seatingChartListContainer h3
{
  width: 20% !important;
}
.seatingChartTable
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
.seats
{
  height: 500px;
}
.seat
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: all;
}
.seat-wrap {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.nameContainer
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <div id="seatingChartListContainer">
     Number of Seats
    <select type="select" id="tableCap" name="tableCap" />
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      </select>
    <p>Assigned to Table</p>
    <div class="nameContainer">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/contacts-xxl.png" width="50" height="50" style="display: inline"/><p style="display: inline">James</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nameContainer">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/contacts-xxl.png" width="50" height="50" style="display: inline"/><p style="display: inline">James</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nameContainer">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/contacts-xxl.png" width="50" height="50" style="display: inline"/><p style="display: inline">James</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nameContainer">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/contacts-xxl.png" width="50" height="50" style="display: inline"/><p style="display: inline">James</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nameContainer">
    <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/contacts-xxl.png" width="50" height="50" style="display: inline"/><p style="display: inline">James</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="seatingChartContainer">
      <div class="seatingChartTableContainer">
  <div class="seatingChartTable"></div>
  <div class="seats"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a raw version of a script file from github, it will not parse as JS due to the different MIME type sent by the server.

Changing the source for that file (`jquery-ui-touch-punch`) seems to get your demo working:

http://jsbin.com/pucadabigo/edit?html,css,console,output

**Edit:** the droppable selector is wrong as well. it should be `.seats`, not `.seat`.

**Edit 2:** turns out it wasn't a typo, but missing seat divs. Added some back in along with css fixes (to clear absolute positioning of the `.nameContainer` element after dragging).

Comment: Thank you, however that still doesn't append the dragged name div to the droppable seat div

Comment: My bad. I realised your selector for the seats element is wrong as well. It should be `.seats`, not `.seat`. I've updated the jsbin to fix this too.

Comment: I should have explained better, i'm sorry. I actually do need it to append to the $(".seat") it is dropped into. I'm saving the html in a database to load later and I want to access the name through a parent-child hierarchy

Comment: I see. Your sample didn't include any seat element so I simply assumed you made a typo error. I added in some seat divs (along with some css to fix alignment). I've added the link to the changed jsbin in my answer.